# How to append value into object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my javascript:

```
var myobject = {};
for(var i = 1; i <= 10 ; i++){
    if(i<=5){
        key = '123'
        if(myobject.key == undefined){
            myobject.key = '';
        }
        myobject.key = myobject.key + 'English';
    }
    else{
        key = '456'
        if(myobject.key == undefined){
            myobject.key = '';
        }
        myobject.key = myobject.key + 'Thai';
    }
}
key = '123';
document.write(myobject.key);
```

If `key = 123` I will append value `English`.
but if `key = 456` I will append value `Thai`.

`document.write(myobject.key)`: it returned result `EnglishEnglishEnglishEnglishEnglishThaiThaiThaiThaiThai`

But I want expected result `EnglishEnglishEnglishEnglish`

Could you help me, please?

Comment: Why do you expect that result? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Because I set key = '123' before document.write(myobject.key);

Comment: You're never using key anywhere though. You let i determine everything. Keep in mind that "key" and "myobject.key" are 2 different things.

Comment: I understand that myobject.key is value.  myobject = { '123' : 'EnglishEnglishEnglishEnglishEnglish', '456' : 'ThaiThaiThaiThaiThai' }

Comment: I think you are meaning to do `myobject[key]` so that the value of key variable is used as the property name. As is you are creating a property literally named `key` and overwriting it in each iteration

Comment: I try to `document.write(myobject[key]);` but response is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing the `key` literal, not `myobject[key]` like you want. You can simplify your code like so:

```
var myobject = {};
 for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
   if (i <= 5) {
     key = '123'
     myobject[key] = (myobject[key] || '') + 'English';
   } else {
     key = '456'
     myobject[key] = (myobject[key] || '') + 'Thai';
   }
 }
 key = '123';
 document.write(myobject[key]);
```